# Error in validityMethod(as(object, superClass)) : object 'Matrix_validate' not found

Tags: r, bioinformatics, r-package, seurat

I just try to use :

```
scRNA <- FindNeighbors(scRNA, dims = pc.num)
```

and

```
scRNA.counts <- Read10X(data.dir = "filtered_feature_bc_matrix")
```

and both of them gives error like :

```
Error in validityMethod(as(object, superClass)) :    object 'Matrix_validate' not found
```

I guess these code totally run well in other's computer

so I wonder what's wrong with my code and how to fix it ?

Comment: I suspect that you need to update Matrix to version 1.5-x: `update.packages("Matrix")`.  Having said that, the fact that the symbol was not found suggests that at least one reverse dependency of Matrix is missing `>= 1.5-0` in its `DESCRIPTION` file.

Comment: Please, bohrxd, do mention the R *package* name of the functions you use,  which would help pin pointing the "culpable" package that needs to add `(>= 1.5-0)` after its `Matrix` dependency.

Comment: thanks for everyone , the good news is that it works after I re-installed the package'Matrix' to  >= 1.5-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, to solve the problem for you, it should be sufficient to do what @Mikael Jagan says:

```
update.packages("Matrix")
```

2nd thought:  The above may not solve the problem entirely:
As there are other packages involved, some of these *may* have to be re-installed (*after* the updating of `Matrix`).

Can you post the output (or good summary of that if it's too long) of

```
 traceback()
```

immediately after producing the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this before function calls:

```
Matrix_validate = "CsparseMatrix_validate"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).